# if condition true do next for loop iteration

Tags: vb.net

I have code like:

```
 For Each dr As DataRow In items.Tables(0).Rows()
     If dr("PRICE") = 0.0 Or dr("PRICE").ToString = "0.0" Then
         'Skip end go in for-each again
     Else
         'Do something else.
     End If
Next
```

I want to know if condition is true (Price is 0) then it should go to next item in for-each and do IF check again. Something like a NEXT?

Comment: ["Continue"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801hyx6f.aspx)

Comment: Your code seems already do what you want.(Just comment/remove line `...Skip end go in for-each again`

Comment: `dr("PRICE").ToString` will never be "0.0" because you have not specified a format string, so you can remove that clause.

Answer (score 0):

As asawyer already pointed out, using the `Continue` Keyword is what you would want to do. It does exactly what you need - it just jumps to the next iteration of the loop specified. In your program it would look like this:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In items.Tables(0).Rows()
    If dr("PRICE") = 0.0 Or dr("PRICE").ToString = "0.0" Then
         Continue For
    Else
          ...Do something else.
    End If
Next
```